# CSS grid: How to make the select element to fill up to the space available in a grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

How to make the select element to fill up to the space available in a grid?

```css
.grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: fit-content(100px) auto;
      width: 100%;
  }

  select {
     max-width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
   <div class="grid-container">
       <div>Time Zone
       </div>
    
       <div>
           <select>
               <option value="1">Time Zone Name very long: about 650px</option>
           </select>
       </div>
    </div>
```

The select width did not shrink to fit into the space.

Comment: Add `min-width:0` to your grid divs, that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell the `select` element to fill all the width in `div` element. By default, `select` is filling up as much space, as the longest `option` in it. You need to add `width: 100%` for the `select`, not `max-width`:

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: fit-content(100px) auto;
    width: 100%;
}

select {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div>Time Zone</div>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option value="1">Time Zone Name very long: about 650px</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```